# Is it possible pull files from other users' google drives using a non-interactive python script?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am kinda lost in google api documentation jungle... need some help

I run a SaaS service hosted on AWS. I want to write a tiny python non-interactive script that

- runs on my linux in AWS
- periodically pulls certain files out of some unrelated google drive users (who want to authorize me to pull these files but I don't know how to guide them)

But I am lost in the liguistic jungle (English is not my mothertongue) of google api docs. Have spent hours with nothing to show... except frustration. I have also gone through many SO posts.

To begin with I can't even tell if this is feasible with google drive. All examples I saw are for App Data and not User Data. I know it would be trivial with AWS S3 or an FTP server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

----EDIT 1 (for Klaus D.)

Below is the scenario that I am trying to map, and the steps I have run so far

1. there is a file owner. This is typically someone from outside my company. I have created a test google account, created a folder and populated a few files in there. I am calling it "file-owner-test@gmail.com"
2. For this user, I created a project "proj-xxx", enabled Drive API, created a service account "prod-xxx-service-account".
3. Next I checked "furnish private key" and which downloaded a JSON file that I saved as "test-credentials.json", transferred to my linux box. I left "domain wide" checkbox unchecked.
4. On my linux box, I am now trying out the python quickstart script shown [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python) , setting credential_path to the downloaded file. But it breaks on `store.get()`:

   store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
   credentials = store.get()

with a crisp `KeyError: _module`.

```
 File "./testprog.py", line 44, in get_credentials
  credentials = store.get()
 File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/oauth2client/client.py", line 421, in get
 File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/oauth2client/file.py", line 66, in locked_get
 File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/oauth2client/client.py", line 317, in new_from_json
KeyError: '_module'
```

I see there are unanswered SO questions on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966906/google-api-quickstart-py-error-keyerror-module) and also on github.

The credentials file looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "proj-xxx",
  "private_key_id": "40-characters-wide-gibberish",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nmulti-line-private-key\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "prod-xxx-service-account@proj-xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "21-digit-number",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/prod-xxx-service-account%proj-xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

So, this is basically trying to get own user data using a credentials file in a non-interactive way. But the API is rather unclear (very secure!!). I probably also have made other mistakes in the steps so far. And I am not yet done - I will next need to add some permissions to this service account!

I hope this adds enough clarity for someone-who-knows to provide a little guidance. Thanks.

Comment: You need an OAuth authorization from the resource owner (user). Where exactly are you having problems? Guiding you through the whole process would be too broad.

Comment: As long as they authenticate once and you save the refresh token you will be able to authenticate again with your non-interactive script.

Comment: @KlausD.I have edited the post to add my steps so far and also where my test script is breaking.

Comment: google api links at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/reference/pydoc are broken - is there another site for looking at the API references? Thanks.