# File "quickstart.py", line 9, in <module>

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I am new in Python and trying use Google Drive Apis, but facing this issue. 
**Error** I am getting after running `python quickstart.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 9, in <module>
    creds = store.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 407, in get
    return self.locked_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/file.py", line 54, in locked_get
    credentials = client.Credentials.new_from_json(content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 302, in new_from_json
    module_name = data['_module']
KeyError: '_module'
```

- I have generated **client_secret.json** file as per the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python) tutorial.
- All the file are in the same directory as that of **quickstart.py**.

Here is how my **quickstart.py** file looks.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# Setup the Drive v3 API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Drive v3 API
results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])
if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

**UPDATE:**
I checked and it turns out that **credentials.json** file is auto-generated on the first run and for some reason, this is not happening.

```
KeyError: '_module'
```

This key **_module** is suppose to be present in **credentials.json** file and that is why this error is thrown. Not sure what is missing. Can someone please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: And your question is?   I dont think creating an empty credeitals.json file is going to work your code will need the credentials to run.

Comment: How to resolve this given error. The downloaded credentials are there in client_secret.json file as per the instructions given in the document. Python Quickstart

Answer (score 1):

[Similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966906/google-api-quickstart-py-error-keyerror-module) Try to remove both files from your directory - "credentials.json" and "client_secret.json". Then re-generate your credentials and re-create "client_secret.json", this worked for me.